# fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6-beta6, xcode6-beta5

Suddenly I'v started getting run time error as,

```
fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
```

I'v declared my array as,

```
var myArray : [CUSTOM_CLASS] = [CUSTOM_CLASS]()
```

Now, in my server response success block  I have,

```
self.myArray = dicResponse["data"]! as Array

println(self.myArray) // FATAL ERROR HERE
```

Which was working perfect before upgrading to Xcode6 Beta6

```
FYI : dicResponse["data"]! // is verified as valid
```

(Sorry to pointing wrong place before!)

**SOLVED :**

Dont know but I'd made some changes and it works,

```
var myArray = [AnyObject]()

self.myArray = dicResponse["data"]! as [AnyObject]
```

Comment: Can you post more info?

Comment: Yes, please, post more code.

Comment: @BaSha please accept one answer if it helped, or write and accept your own for future reference, **instead of writing your solution in the question**.

Comment: I had the same issue, but my solution was the error in subclassing a Parse PFObject - in the new Swift 1.7.1 parse release.

Comment: Had the same error using Parse as well. @BaSha your solution worked perfectly, thanks for the update!

Answer (score 20):

If I could supplement Teejay's answer with some further information. This error:

```
fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
```

is caused by a type mismatch.

For example having cast to your Swift array type:

```
    myPersonList = aDictionary["persons"] as [Person]
```

Accessing the value in aDictionary based upon key `"persons"`, Swift expects to receive **an array of type Person**. This will compile and will execute without issue.

However, later in your code when accessing the `myPersonList` array element, if the type is not as specified - in my example **Person** - then execution will crash with the error above.

**Bottom line: you almost certainly have specified the wrong type in the cast. Examine your dictionary object to see what it really contains.**

Comment: This answer worked for me! I thought I had run into an unresolved issue because I was using a class in [two different frameworks and trying to archive/unarchive the objects on the watch/ios](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11452), and then got this error message. I thought the reason it was complaining was because it was actually two different frameworks. However, the real problem was that I was accidentally wrapping my array of objects in another array.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with Cocoa APIs you always receive a `NSArray`, which is **not** typified.

So, you need to cast that array to a Typified Swift Array.

You should be able to compile this code:

```
var myArray : [CUSTOM_CLASS] = [CUSTOM_CLASS]()

self.myArray = dicResponse["data"]! as [CUSTOM_CLASS]
```

This way, each array element is casted to a `CUSTOM_CLASS` object.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be a conflict between swift type and ObjectiveC's one?
Because I experienced a similar situation trying to loop on a `[NSMutableDisctionary]` both with `.forEach{}` and `for ... in` way, but it gave me your same error (`NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type`). When I changed the type to `[Dictionary<String,Any>]` all worked well. Now, `[]` was introduced in Swift, and types with prefix `NS...` in ObjectiveC.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Also caused by mixing Xcode 7 and Xcode 7.1 binaries.

This has already been answered, but I just got this error in the bowels of Alamofire for an array cast of a valid [String].

In my case, I was using carthage and had not realized that xcode-select was still pointing at the crash-happy Xcode 7.  Updating xcode-select to Xcode 7.1B fixed my problem.