# How to Solve NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type in GooglePlaces API findAutocompletePredictions?

Tags: google-places-api, swift5

I am having trouble analyzing the results given by the callback of `GMSPlacesClient findAutocompletePredictionsFromQuery:`, which is a GMSAutocompletePrediction array.

The app will crash on `let searchResultsWayPoints = finalResults.map` ,
stating

```
Precondition failed: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
Expected GMSAutocompletePrediction but found GMSAutocompletePrediction
```

```
func getGoogleWayPoint(text: String) -> Promise<[GoogleWayPoint]> {
        return Promise<[GoogleWayPoint]> { resolver in
            if text.isEmpty {
                resolver.fulfill([])
                return
            }
            placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(fromQuery: text, filter: filter, sessionToken: sessionToken) { (results, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    dprint(error.localizedDescription)
                    resolver.fulfill([])
                    return
                }


                guard let finalResults = results else {
                    dprint("can't found results")
                    resolver.fulfill([])
                    return
                }
                let searchResultsWayPoints = finalResults.map {
                    GoogleWayPoint(id: $0.placeID, address: $0.attributedFullText.string)
                }
                resolver.fulfill(searchResultsWayPoints)
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484554/fatal-error-nsarray-element-failed-to-match-the-swift-array-element-type

Comment: Actually, it is not really a dupe, as their solution doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have solved this problem, but I did not fix anything, since it is from the GooglePlaces framework.

In order to solve this, simply make `results` as `results:[Any]?` at the callback.

Then, at `guard let`, safely convert it to `[GMSAutocompletePrediction]`.

Here is the complete code

```
func getGoogleWayPoint(text: String) -> Promise<[GoogleWayPoint]> {
        return Promise<[GoogleWayPoint]> { resolver in
            if text.isEmpty {
                resolver.fulfill([])
                return
            }
            placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(fromQuery: text, filter: filter, sessionToken: sessionToken) { (results: [Any]?, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    dprint(error.localizedDescription)
                    resolver.fulfill([])
                    return
                }


                guard let finalResults = results as? [GMSAutocompletePrediction] else {
                    dprint("can't found results")
                    resolver.fulfill([])
                    return
                }
                let searchResultsWayPoints = finalResults.map {
                    GoogleWayPoint(id: $0.placeID, address: $0.attributedFullText.string)
                }
                resolver.fulfill(searchResultsWayPoints)
            }
        }
    }
```